# Alternate design for multiple inheritance

Tags: java

My program takes data from different file types and inserts them into different DBs depending on the department which uploaded the file.

To accomplish this, I have a base abstract class `AbstractHandler` which has some methods which are unimplemented and some which are common to all children. Two types of abstract classes extend from this class, `InputTypeAHandler`, `InputTypeBHandler`, etc. and `OutputTypeAHandler`, `OutputTypeBHandler`, etc. These abstract classes also implement some more methods but not all.

I have concrete classes which I want to extend from these two types of classes and which will implement some more methods specific to every class. For example,

```
abstract class AbstractHandler {
  public void method1() {
    // ....
  }
  public abstract void method2();
  public abstract void method3();
  public abstract void method4();
}
abstract class InputTypeAHandler extends AbstractHandler {
  @Override
  public void method2() {
    // ....
  }
}
abstract class OutputTypeBHandler extends AbstractHandler {
  @Override
  public void method3() {
    // ....
  }
}

public class ConcreteHandler1 extends InputTypeAHandler, OutputTypeBHandler {
  @Override
  public void method4() {
    // ....
  }
}
public class ConcreteHandler2 extends InputTypeCHandler, OutputTypeAHandler {
  @Override
  public void method4() {
    // ....
  }
}
```

Since Java does not allow multiple inheritance, how do I do this?

Comment: It looks like you should have separate interfaces for `InputHandler` and `OutputHandler`, and use composition instead.

Comment: @Sweeper I can't use interfaces as these `InputHandler`s and `OutputHandler`s have methods that are already implemented and I don't want to repeat them in every concrete class.

Comment: Can you show where those methods are implemented? I think your question is missing quite a lot of details about what you want to be able to do.

Comment: @Sweeper I have added an example.

Comment: Does all `InputTypeXHandler`s implement `method2`? and does all `OutputTypeXHandler`s implement `method3`?

Comment: @Sweeper Yes all InputTypeXHandlers implement method2. and all OutputTypeXHandlers implement method3.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to implement some kind of conversion between any pair of A,B,C... types (perhaps formats?). If it is the case, the `AbstractHandler` probably has multiple responsibilities. Split its logic to part involving source format and part involving target format. You can inspire in [converter pattern](https://java-design-patterns.com/patterns/converter/) or [GoF Bridge pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/bridge).

Comment: It's actually taking data from different file types and inserting them into different DBs depending on the department which uploaded the file.

Answer (score 1):

I use lombok and the power of interfaces for this:

```
public class Test implements InputTypeAHandler,OutputTypeAHandler {
    @Delegate
    OutputTypeAHandlerImp outputTypeAHandlerImp = new OutputTypeAHandlerImp() {
      @Override
      String id() {
        return "mellow";
      }
    };
    @Delegate
    InputTypeAHandlerImp inputTypeAHandler = new InputTypeAHandlerImp(){
      @Override
      String id() {
        return "hello124";
      }
    };
    
  }


  public static abstract class OutputTypeAHandlerImp implements OutputTypeAHandler {

    abstract String id();
    
    @Override
    public void write(String s) {
      System.out.println(s);
    }
  }
  
  public static abstract class InputTypeAHandlerImp implements InputTypeAHandler {
    abstract String id();
    
    @Override
    public String read() {
      return new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
    }
  }
  
  public interface InputTypeAHandler {
    String read();
  }

  public interface OutputTypeAHandler{
    void write(String s);
  }
```